# Converting SQL server query to its equivalent MySQL for trigger

Tags: mysql, database-trigger

In SQL Server, we can get the last inserted record using ***inserted*** table in triggers. I know the equivalent MySQL statement is NEW. But the question is how to implement that.
A snippet is attached herewith what it shows in SQL Server. I want the very same thing in MySQL. Will it be possible to do that?
[image: Trigger Query]

I want the output as:
[image: Trigger Output]

Please give the total implementation. I've tried NEW in different ways those didn't work out.
Thanks.

Comment: What did you try in MySQL, why didn't it work?  What is your old code trying to do? It seems to be a trigger that does nothing,

Comment: @JeffUK, I tried to show the last record without storing it in a new table. Let's take this query as an example: Select * from Customer. You know It returns a table. The same thing I tried to do in my code. That is, when the trigger will be fired, only the last inserted record will be shown as the result of the query/trigger. To see the result I need to go the tblEmployeeAudit manually.That's the main problem I am facing here.

Comment: If you've got some time @JeffUK, please just skim through the link. To be specific see only from 7th-8th minutes. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k0S4P-a6d5w

Comment: Thanks, I see what it does in SQL Sever now. Please edit your question to include the code you have tried (as text, not a screenshot) to replicate that in MySQL, and detail why it doesn't work as expected.

Comment: @JeffUK, What I tried to do is that, just show the last entry without inserting the values into another table. What i tried is:  `CREATE TRIGGER `Insert` AFTER INSERT ON `customer` FOR EACH ROW Select new.ID, new.Name;` The error message is: **Not allowed to return a result set from a trigger**.

Comment: Sounds like you have your answer, MySQL doesn’t allow you to return rows in a trigger